# Calculated sum/count by category and sort descending, together with an inner join

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a simple table. One column with a variable which I want to sum or count and another one with category. I tried this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS counted, category
FROM mytable
GROUP BY category
ORDER BY counted DESC;
```

With out the `ORDER BY counted DESC` it works, however it is not sorted. I would like to see the maximum immediately, so sort descending. However, when running it, a message pops up and asks me to insert a value for counted. Why can't I do this in one step, why is this not working?

Same for sum:

```
SELECT sum(variable) AS calcsum, category
FROM mytable
GROUP BY category
ORDER BY calcsum DESC;
```

Furthermore I have the same problem or similiar when trying to do this in one step with a join. I have one table with provided IDs (variable called keys). Another table with IDs, a category, a filter variable and a score. I want the sum of score per category and sort it descending. So far I have:

```
SELECT SUM(score) AS calcsum, category

FROM (

SELECT keys, category, filter, score INTO newdataset
FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.keys=table2.ID
WHERE table2.filter="Value")

GROUP BY category;
```

And I thought here again to add: `ORDER BY calcsum DESC`

However, even without adding the ORDER BY I get the error message "An action query cannot be used as a row source". So what is my mistake here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just repeat the `COUNT(*)` expression:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS counted, category
FROM mytable
GROUP BY category
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

EDIT:

If you want this with `INTO` and `JOIN`s:

```
SELECT SUM(score) AS calcsum, category
INTO newdataset
FROM table1 INNER JOIN
     table2
     ON table1.keys  =table2.ID
WHERE table2.filter = "Value"
GROUP BY category
ORDER BY SUM(score) DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks +1 that works, however it does not work in case of my inner join example, so the third block of code.

Comment: @StatTistician . . . I edited the answer.  The idea is the same:  you need to use the expression not the column.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works! However, I have one more question: I now want to select the maximum value, so not the whole list, but from this the maximum value (the first one, since it is sorted). I wanted to to the following:
SELECT category, max(calcsum) FROM ( [here comes the whole previous query] ); But this does not work? I also tried to select the first row with SELECT TOP 1 * FROM ([here comes the whole previous query]) but same problem here, I always get the message "An action query cannot be used as a row source"?

Comment: @StatTistician . . . I've already sufficiently answered this question.  If you have a *new* question, ask it as a *new* question.

Comment: You are right, I accepted your answer. My new question is here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61008113/select-max-of-sum-and-max-of-count-of-a-subquery

Answer (score 1):

simply you can use `order by 2 desc` 2 stands for the second column in your select statement