# Select max of sum and max of count of a subquery

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a query which gives me the sum and counts per category. It is sorted descending. The first value is the max value, so the highest sum and highest count.

```
SELECT SUM(score) AS calcsum, category
INTO newdataset
FROM table1 INNER JOIN
     table2
     ON table1.keys  =table2.ID
WHERE table2.filter = "Value"
GROUP BY category
ORDER BY SUM(score) DESC;
```

resp.

```
SELECT count(*) as counted, category
INTO newdataset
FROM table1 INNER JOIN
     table2
     ON table1.keys  =table2.ID
WHERE table2.filter = "Value"
GROUP BY category
ORDER BY count(*) DESC;
```

However, now I do not want a list, I just want the maximium value. I want to implement it first with max of count and max of sum. And second way is to just extract the first observation of the list.

First method I tried:

```
SELECT category, MAX(calcsum)
FROM (
SELECT SUM(score) AS calcsum, category
INTO newdataset
FROM table1 INNER JOIN
     table2
     ON table1.keys  =table2.ID
WHERE table2.filter = "Value"
GROUP BY category
ORDER BY SUM(score) DESC);
```

resp.

```
SELECT category, MAX(counted)
FROM (
SELECT count(*) AS counted, category
INTO newdataset
FROM table1 INNER JOIN
     table2
     ON table1.keys  =table2.ID
WHERE table2.filter = "Value"
GROUP BY category
ORDER BY count(*) DESC);
```

Which leads to an error message "An action query cannot be used as a row source".

Second way I tried:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * 
 FROM (
    SELECT SUM(score) AS calcsum, category
    INTO newdataset
    FROM table1 INNER JOIN
         table2
         ON table1.keys  =table2.ID
    WHERE table2.filter = "Value"
    GROUP BY category
    ORDER BY SUM(score) DESC);
```

resp.

```
SELECT TOP 1 * 
 FROM (
    SELECT SUM(score) AS calcsum, category
    INTO newdataset
    FROM table1 INNER JOIN
         table2
         ON table1.keys  =table2.ID
    WHERE table2.filter = "Value"
    GROUP BY category
    ORDER BY SUM(score) DESC);
```

Same error here. What is the problem here, why is it not working and I do not understand the error message? I would like to have working solutios for both ways, how would a working solution look like?

*Update*:
I tried according to the answers:

```
SELECT category, max(calcsum)
INTO newdataset
FROM (SELECT SUM(score) AS calcsum, category      
      FROM table1 INNER JOIN
           table2
           ON table1.keys = table2.ID
      WHERE table2.filter = "Value"
      GROUP BY category
     ) t;
```

However, I get an error message (category is not part of the aggregate function, translated)?

I also tried:

```
 SELECT t.category, max(calcsum)
    INTO newdataset
    FROM (SELECT SUM(score) AS calcsum, category      
          FROM table1 INNER JOIN
               table2
               ON table1.keys = table2.ID
          WHERE table2.filter = "Value"
          GROUP BY category
         ) t;
```

But same error. So how would a working solution using the max way and not top look like?

When I try this:

```
 SELECT category, calcsum
    INTO newdataset
    FROM (SELECT SUM(score) AS calcsum, category      
          FROM table1 INNER JOIN
               table2
               ON table1.keys = table2.ID
          WHERE table2.filter = "Value"
          GROUP BY category
         ) t;
```

It works, but when I add max(calcsum), I get the error (category is not part of the aggregate function, translated)?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the just the top record in the resultset, why not simply limit the returned rows in the outer query?

```
SELECT TOP (1) SUM(score) AS calcsum, category
INTO newdataset
FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.keys = table2.ID
WHERE table2.filter = "Value"
GROUP BY category
ORDER BY SUM(score) DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however I also need a working solution for using max of sum(score). I tried to implement it according to the answers here, but it does not work. I updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your versions do not work is because `INTO` is only allowed in the *outermost* query.  You are trying to put it in a subquery.  In addition:

- `ORDER BY` is generally not allowed in a subquery.
- Subqueries in the `FROM` clause need a table alias.

So, the errors multiple.

For instance, you could write the last query as:

```
SELECT TOP (1) t.* 
INTO newdataset
FROM (SELECT SUM(score) AS calcsum, category      
      FROM table1 INNER JOIN
           table2
           ON table1.keys = table2.ID
      WHERE table2.filter = "Value"
      GROUP BY category
     ) t
ORDER BY SUM(score) DESC;
```

As GMB points out, you don't need a subquery for this logic.

I would point out that if you have duplicates for the maximum values, then the logic chooses an arbitrary maximum.  If you want all of them, use `TOP (1) WITH TIES`.

I would go one step further and question why you need this in a *new* table.  Why not just store the values in parameters if you want to use the in subsequent processing?

Comment: Thanks for your post. This works as a solution for the second way, however I need a solution also for my first method. I tried to implement it in the way you say, but it does not work. I updated my question.

Comment: @StatTistician . . . Exactly the same idea.  The `into` goes in the outer query.  The derived table needs an alias.  The `order by` goes in the outer query.

Comment: I did so and updated my question, however it does not work.

Comment: @StatTistician . . . You would not use `MAX()` to get the category with the largest value.  Use `ORDER BY` instead.

Comment: But I need to have the solution for the method where max() is used and not ordered/sorted. So take the max of the sum, from the table which was not sorted. Regardless of the sort order get the max value of the calculated sums.

Answer (score 0):

Frankly, I do not understand the reason why you require to not using top/order-by as suggested by GMB.

Anyway, here's the query using MAX() function.
Please be aware, this is a costly query.

```
SELECT SUM(score) AS calcsum, category 
INTO newdataset
FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.keys = table2.id 
WHERE table2.filter = "Value" 
GROUP BY category 
HAVING SUM(score) = (
    SELECT MAX(sc) 
    FROM (
        SELECT SUM(score) AS sc
        FROM table1 
        INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.keys = table2.id 
        WHERE table2.filter = "Value" 
        GROUP BY category
      )
  )
```

And the same principle applied to counted:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS counted, category 
INTO newdataset
FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.keys = table2.id 
WHERE table2.filter = "Value" 
GROUP BY category 
HAVING COUNT(*) = (
    SELECT MAX(sc) 
    FROM (
        SELECT COUNT(*) AS sc
        FROM table1 
        INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.keys = table2.id 
        WHERE table2.filter = "Value" 
        GROUP BY category
      )
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there any specific purpose to use sub-query format as this queries can also return output without using sub-queries.
Any way you have sorted the "calcsum" in descending order. Limit should do the job for you.

```
SELECT SUM(score) AS calcsum, category
FROM table1 INNER JOIN
 table2
 ON table1.keys  =table2.ID
WHERE table2.filter = "Value"
GROUP BY category
ORDER BY calcsum DESC LIMIT 1
```